# Is there an alternative for overwriting the abstract method in the example cited?

Tags: java, overriding, abstract-class

I'm having a question about the implementation of this example here: https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/examples/phone-calls-migration-java. We have an abstract method inside a nested abstract static class:

```
public class PhoneCallsCSVMigration {
    /**
     * representation of Input object that links an input file to its own templating function,
     * which is used to map a Json object to a Graql query string
     */
    abstract static class Input {
        String path;

        public Input(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        String getDataPath() {
            return path;
        }

        abstract String template(Json data);
    }
...
```

Later on, the abstract method `template(Json data)` is overridden with the aim of obtaining a `graqlInsertQuery`:

```
inputs.add(new Input("files/phone-calls/data/companies") {
            @Override
            public String template(Json company) {
                return "insert $company isa company, has name " + company.at("name") + ";";
            }
        });
```

First of all, how is it even possible to instantiate something of the type `Input`? And secondly, where does the `Json company` come from? I want to split up the `PhoneCallsCSVMigration` class into several classes like `Input`, `GraknHandler`, `QueryHandler` etc., and I'm wondering how I can define the template for constructing a Graql insert query other than overriding the abstract class. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidenty externally an Input child is created with a `path` and implementing template.
Probably this object is passed to the surrounding class and it calls `template` passing `Json` data.

The abstract method could just as easily be replaced by a `Function<Json, String>` but then that function would miss the `path`, so one could use `BiFunction<String, Json, String>`.

You have to look where and when the path and Json come from. Here it seems a bit artificial. Instead of an static inner class as above, a traditional (very similar) pattern would be:

```
abstract class A {
    public final void func() { // Some service offered by this class.
        B b = ...;
        C c = onFunc(b);
    }

    abstract protected C onFunc(B b); // Some requirement to implement.
}
```

- Here `func` is for users of A, a service.
- And `onFunc` is for implementors of A to fulfill a specific requirement.

So out of context as in your case is a bit weird or over-engineered. Just passing a callback function would seem to do.

Comment: In fact it did seem artifical to me, this is why my question came up.

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, how is it even possible to instantiate something of the
>   type Input?

You're not instantiating class `Input`. You're creating an instance of an anonymous class that derives from `Input` and that implements its abstract method `template`.

> where does the `Json company` come from?

It comes from the one that will invoke the `template` method, passing it as the parameter.

I leave the rest of the question to somebody who understood it...

Comment: Instead of answering disparagingly, please state what's unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be disparaging. It's just that I had an answer to the first 2 questions but I actually didn't understand the last part, which I consider my lack of knowledge.